# For-of loop in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, for-loop, dictionary

Firefox browser console is returning the expected answer. But when I run the below code in Chrome console it is returning back `Unexpected token [`. Version of my Chrome browser is 44, while `map` and `for...of` methods are compatible from version 38. Why does the Chrome console cause an error?

```
var map = new Map();
map.set(3, "Fizz");
map.set(5, "Buzz");
for (var [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    if (6 % key == 0) console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the ECMA 6 features enabled in Chrome?

Comment: It looks very convoluted, not sure what you are trying to do but looks like `for (var item of map) {
    if (6 % item[0] == 0) console.log(item[0]);
}`

Comment: Yes Xotic750, that is the only way how you loop Map objects

Comment: @developer No it's not, have a peak at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
"Maps can be iterated using a for..of loop:". Iterate it with any other sort of loop in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ScratchJS](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=scratchjs), Google Chrome does not seem to support all ECMA6. You are right `for...of` should be supported and it is indeed supported. What is not supported is the unpacking of values. Check the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) at the index `destructuring, assignement`, only `Chrome 49` seems to have **partial** support for it.

If you try to remove the unpacking it will work.

```
 var map = new Map();
 map.set(3, "Fizz");
 map.set(5, "Buzz");
 for (var value of map.entries()) {
    console.log(value[0]);
 }
```

Comment: I have not tried it with Chrome 49, you can give it a shot. But cannot assure that it will work.

Comment: it is working in Chrome 44, so in 49 it work as well